# Null reference c#

Tags: c#, object

Im writing a code where  you can search a name and the subjects teaches will pop-up etc..

however I'm not really sure why but i'm getting *Object reference not set to an instance of an object* error im missing something i know, can someone help me? i tried different methods didn't really work... heres my code :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Course my = new Course();
        public class Course
        {

            public string[] Name { get; set; }
            public string[] Subject { get; set; }
            public string[] Hour { get; set; }

            public Course(string[] name, string[] subject, string[] hour)
            {
                this.Name = name;
                this.Subject = subject;
                this.Hour = hour;

            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            my.Name[0] = "Ali";
            my.Name[1] = "Sefer";

            my.Subject[0] = "INFORMATIKA";
            my.Subject[1] = "ENGLISH";

            my.Hour[0] = "12";
            my.Hour[1] = "22";

        }

        private void searchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Find();
        }


        private void Find()
        {

            int index = 0;
            string wanted = wantedName.Text;

            while (my.Name[index] != wanted && (my.Name[index] != "END"))
            {
                index++;
            }
            if (my.Name[index] == wanted)
            {
                outputLabel.Content = " " + my.Name[index] + " "  + my.Subject[index];
            }
            else
            {
                outputLabel.Content = "Name not found";
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: How does this even compile? `Course my = new Course();` is calling a constructor that doesn't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using arrays without initializing them. While you have defined a constructor for your `Course` class that takes values for the arrays, you are using the default constructor. Try calling your own constructor with arguments like

```
Course my = new Course(new string[2], new string[2], new string[2]);
```

Before you can assign a value to an element like `my.Name[0]`, you have to ensure that `my.Name` is referencing an allocated array, which means there is memory available for your elements.

Comment: There is no default constructor in OPs code, their code shouldn't even compile

Comment: I agree, the code as posted is flawed. The OP's original code might still compile.

Comment: How might it compile? A class can only have an implicit default constructor if no user-defined one exists. Since OP defined one constructor there is no default constructor anymore

Comment: Maybe he posted only part of his code. Who knows? It seems he has running code as he gets a runtime exception.

Comment: I see now.... thx a lot! gonna study more, everything works perfectly now!